# What are the signs that an interview went well ( or badly )?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I have been attending lot of interviews recently as a new graduate. What are the signs that one can get from HRs and interviewers that the interview well ( or badly )?

Comment: Signs that it went well? You get the job.

Comment: Hey Surya, and welcome to [workplace.se]! As-is this question has been voted by the community to be too broad because it is a bit too open-ended. As explained in our [help/dont-ask] open-ended questions aren't the best fit for our format. Is there any chance you could [edit] to focus on an practical answerable question based on actual problems you face? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to tell if it went badly than if it went well. The sign that it went well is when you get a call back for another interview or a job offer. The best interviews you have may not result in moving further into the process because you are competing with others and someone else may have been much better than you were. So even if you feel good about what you said, it is not a sign that you are getting the job.

Signs it went especially badly are if they cut off the interview rather abruptly, if people seem to be going through the motions and not paying attention to what you said or if you know that you very badly missed the answers on several questions.

Answer (score 2):

I am a fellow job seeker too. I feel if they say a time scale by which you will hear from us, I think it is a good sign that they are thinking about the next step. Another thing is showing around the building. If they are willing to put an effort to show you around the building, then that is a good sign.

Answer (score 1):

A sign that the interview went well is when the interviewer(s) tell you what next steps are before you ask - they may already be envisioning you moving to the next step!